# Federal powers on Indian reservation

Tags: united-states

If a federal agency such as ATF, FBI, or Homeland Security wants to investigate a disappearance of 10 people from an Indian reservation, can they enter and investigate the alleged crime without permission from the tribal council or another recognized authority of the reservation?

Comment: This is more of a question for https://law.stackexchange.com than politics stackexchange. General rule of thumb: When you want to know "what's the legal situation?" you go to law, when you want to know "why is this the legal situation?" you go to politics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's ontopic for law.se